# Show that if $V_{p^k} = V_{p^{k+1}}$, then $V_{p^m} = V_{p^k}$ for all $m\ge k$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T: V\to V$ be a linear operator and $p\in P(\mathbb{F})$, where $P(\mathbb{F})$ is the set of polinomials over a field $\mathbb{F}$. Define 
>   $$
> V_p =\{ v\in V : p(T)(v) = 0\}.
> $$ 
>   Show that if $$V_{p^k} = V_{p^{k+1}}$$ for some $k>0$, then 
>   $$
> V_{p^m} = V_{p^k}
> $$
>   for all $m\ge k$.

Once we have
$$
\{0\} \subseteq V_p \subseteq V_{p^2} \subseteq V_{p^3}\cdots
$$
I can't see why this can be valid without the hipothesis that $dim(V)<\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because each term $V_{p^{k+1}}$ depends on the previous one as follows:
$$V_{p^{k+1}} = p^{-1}( V_{p^{k}})$$ so if we have two consecutive terms equal then the next consecutive terms are, and so on, but that means all of the next ones are equal.

Comment: I still can't see why this can imply that $V_{p^{k+1}} = V_{p^k}$ implies that all the next ones are equal

Comment: @FryanBury: take $p^{-1}$ of both sides of the equality

Comment: @orangeskid What is $p^{-1}(V_{p^k})$?  I see that $V_{p^k} = \ker(p^k(T))$ (I assume that's the $k$th power of the polynomial $p$), so how do we apply $p^{-1}$ to a subspace?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: preimage

Comment: @orangeskid that would only make sense if $V_{p^k}$ were a subset of $\Bbb F$, the codomain of $p$. So what are you really trying to say?